# Can't find layout ID for < 1% of users?

Tags: android

I have an app which gets several thousand users a day. I'm getting a handful of reports through marketplace that my entry activity can't load its layout xml resource. I don't see how this could be possible?:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.me.app/com.me.app.MyActivity}: **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030065**
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030065
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:896)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1873)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:735)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
at com.me.app.MyBaseActivity.setContentView(MyBaseActivity.java:50)
at com.me.app.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:116)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
... 11 more
```

The exception points to this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong here? Again, for 99% of users, no problem.

Thank you

Comment: I've been experiencing something similar. So far it's only happened once for approximately 5,000 users (at least it's only been reported once). Very interested to hear if anyone knows why this is.

Comment: Is there any correlation with devices used and/or software/OS versions?

Comment: where my_layout.xml is located ? do you supporting multiple screens ?

Comment: Have you checked the resource with ID=0x7f030065? Is it yours or the one in `android.R`?

Comment: For devices, reported on Nexus One, and Droid. No info about OS version. Yes resource ID 0x7f030065 is indeed mine, checked my compiled R file, it matches ok. I do have a few different layout files , but there is only one "my_layout" file.

Comment: it could be the result of pirated/hacked apks that are getting distributed

Comment: If you are supporting multiple screen sizes/densities then it's a possibility that these < 1% of users are on a device(s) that you didn't provide a layout xml file for. What is the lowest version of Android you are supporting?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments on the question that troubleshooting resource ID 0x7f030065 is the key to understanding these error reports.

I'm assuming that resource is NOT the my_layout file.  Despite my_layout being pointed to as the line of the problem, it most likely is not the root issue.  Something inside the my_layout file is referring to resource 0x7f030065.  The layout inflater often does not report these errors very clearly.

If there isn't a version of 0x7f030065 in a default folder (ex: drawable instead of drawable-landscape), then perhaps the 1% is running in a configuration that can't find it is falling back to the non-existent default.  This could be possible even if your app is locked in landscape orientation for instance - occasionally a portrait draw could still happen - even if it's not visible to the end user.

Is it always the same resource id?  That's a good thing to pay attention to.

In my experience, other issues like running out of memory can cause these sorts of inflate time exceptions.  If resource 0x7f030065 refers to a custom layout class, then anything that happens in the constructor of that class could possibly result in a Resources$NotFoundException

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced something similar.
I was having an activity that I wanted to show only in landscape - so in AndroidManifest.xml I had android:screenOrientation="landscape".
Than a folder layout-land and there my layout file.

From time to time, randomly, I was getting a Resources$NotFoundException when the activity was trying to load the main layout.

I solved it by renaming folder layout-land to layout.

But I think we hit some kind of bug in android.